# Training and Testing Splitting Tagging

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, split

Here is my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd 
fileName= 'user.csv'
df = pd.read_csv("trainingsample_100k_apps.csv",sep=",",header=0)
pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
df

UserID  Total Usage
001       20.3
002       40.5
003       10.1
```

How can I know which row have been selected as training and testing after I applied this query:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.20)
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
UserID  Total Usage   SplitingCategory
001       20.3        Training
002       40.5        Testing
003       10.1        Training
```

Comment: Can you please share the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the answer

```
test
```

and it will appear my test dataset